# Place two JLabels above each other with JTextfields next to them

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, border-layout

I have this code:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                panel.add(textfield, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
                panel.add(textfield2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
                panel.add(button5);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                label.setText("Geef de basis van de driehoek in cm: ");
                label2.setText("Geef de hoogte van de driehoek in cm: ");
            }
        });
```

Which corresponds with this screenshot:

[image]

I want it to actually look like this:

[image]

I'm new to Java and I know this is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure it out with information on the Internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided then I see that the top three buttons are not added in this method so I suppose that they are already there:

In that case lets break your GUI down into bits, like so:

[image]

We can now make those three left over rechtangles. These rectangles are going to be `JPanels` each having the corresponding components in them:

So:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //panel with label and textield
            JPanel base = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            base.add(label, Borderlayout.LINE_START);
            base.add(textfield, BorderLayout.LINE_END)
            panel.add(base, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);//top of the page this may interfere with your three buttons I don't know where you are in your layout structure

            //panel with label2 and textfield2
            JPanel height = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            height.add(label2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            height.add(textfield2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            panel.add(height, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //button5 doesn't need a panel of it's own as it's only one component
            panel.add(button5, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            label.setText("Geef de basis van de driehoek in cm: ");
            label2.setText("Geef de hoogte van de driehoek in cm: ");
        }
    });
```

And that should solve your problem, if you have any questions regarding the answer please let me know.

I hope this helps :)

EDIT #1:

Code version 2:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            //panel with label and textield
            JPanel base = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            base.add(label, Borderlayout.LINE_START);
            base.add(textfield, BorderLayout.LINE_END)
            content.add(base, BorderLayout.PAGE_START

            //panel with label2 and textfield2
            JPanel height = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            height.add(label2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            height.add(textfield2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            content.add(height, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel forbutton5 = new JPanel();
            forbutton5.add(button5);
            content.add(forbutton5, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            panel.add(content);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            label.setText("Geef de basis van de driehoek in cm: ");
            label2.setText("Geef de hoogte van de driehoek in cm: ");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I run your code, the JLabels and Textfields are still on the same line. Why is that?

Comment: Well one label and one textfield should be on one line. But not both could you maybe post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: I think I have a solution I'm going to rewrite the code a little

Comment: Just the BorderLayout

Comment: Added a new version of the code. I think that this 'new' version would solve your problem.

Comment: You're welcome (graag gedaan ;), Good luck with the rest of you code :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer of Roan:
I am not sure what layout manager you are using. Panel has a FlowLayout as default layout manager, and that one puts all components on 1 line. I think you have to use a GridLayout,or a GridbagLayout, and then your components will appear one above the other

Answer (score 2):

Check out the the [visual guide to layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). What you're probably looking for is the GridBagLayout. The following might be something like what you want:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()) // This should be set earlier
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(label, c);
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            panel.add(label2, c);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(textfield, c);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 2;
            panel.add(textfield2, c);
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(button5, c);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            label.setText("Geef de basis van de driehoek in cm: ");
            label2.setText("Geef de hoogte van de driehoek in cm: ");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But do you know a way to get the whole at the top of the page, and not in the center?

Comment: The whole what? My example might not work correctly because you had layout stuff set earlier. The best way would be to specify the layout whenever you create the other two buttons, and lay them out with the constraints variable as well. I've found the best way to figure Swing layouts out is to play with values until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using BorderLayout for this you have to use GridBagLayout.

For More : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html